# AdMob interstitials in app with single activity

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I'm considering replacing regular ads with interstitials in our apps. I've got numerous emails from AdMob encouraging me to do this.

The problem is that our apps are live wallpapers so there's only one actual activity in them - live wallpaper settings. I can't think of any good implementation of interstitials periodic appearance.

According to guidelines, this type of ads must be shown between some interactions, like navigating from one activity to another.

I can show fullscreen ads every time after returning from live wallpaper settings activity to home screen, making sure user haven't seen interstitial like 3 min before (so users don't see them too often, because they can go to settings quite often).

It is possible to use AdMob interstitial ads in such scenario or not?

Comment: some advice - *I've got numerous emails from AdMob encouraging me to do this.* - this is not a good reason to do that. You should not let a 3rd party whose only goal is to make money tell you how to shape your app. Interstitial ads are extremely intrusive

Comment: Yes, that's why I hesitate to add interstitials. AdMob previously contacted me to fix some banner layout issues so now I'm afraid of making UX mistakes w/ something more annoying than a single banner.

Answer (score 0):

> I can show fullscreen ads every time after returning from live
>   wallpaper settings activity to home screen, making sure user haven't
>   seen interstitial like 3 min before (so users don't see them too
>   often, because they can go to settings quite often).

This is good, can be implemented...

However, you can also use / show Interstitial Ads on App Exits...

For e.g. > User Presses Back > Load Interstitial > Ad Closed > Show App Exit Confirmation Dialog > User selects Exit > Call finish();

but if you do this - 
User Presses Back > Load Interstitial > Ad Closed > Call finish() -- This is against policy...

Comment: I don't have any exit confirmations, it is just returning from live wallpaper settings to home screen (or a live wallpaper preview screen).

Comment: @keaukraine What I meant was, if you implement Exit Interstitials, you cannot close App as its a violation... You can either show an Exit Confirmation Dialog or use some other logic which will include to show a different screen after Ad is closed... :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to settings you should load the ad and whenever user click on some button check if the ad is loaded, if it is then show the ad and perform the action on ad closed, else perform the action.
You can also use shared preferences to keep record of user interaction. Set a specific limit and when shared preferences reaches that call for the ad load